# How to access data base in asset folder for android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-assets

Hi I am having separate data base with tables. I need to put/save that data base into my asset folder. And then i want fetch data form that data base what i have stored in my asset folder. Any body can tell me how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On run time copy the database from the asset folder to the app data folder

Answer (score 1):

As per my search first of all we have to copy our data base and paste it in our asset folder.
And then follow this link http://android-vogue.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-get-data-in-listview-from-assets.html we will access the data base. I did it by this way. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read the database directly from the asset folder, so You have to copy the database, for example into the apps storage. Define the path like this

```
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.yourpackage.package/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "yourdatabase.dat";
```

And with this mehod it should work to copy:

```
   private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{

    InputStream mInput = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    File createOutFile = new File(outFileName);
    if(!createOutFile.exists()){
        createOutFile.mkdir();
    }
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
    {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}
```

But then You have to create a Database class like You have to do when You want to create a new Database. This is beyond the frame to tell here, but should give You a direction where to start.